# Sub-aggregation or aggregation filter in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a list of records with name and timestamp. For each name, I want to get the maximal timestamp, but I only want to get names with max timestamp before an hour ago (meaning that in my result I would only like to see a list of names and their max timestamp, but only for names that has max timestamp before an hour ago. If a name has a record with timestamp after an hour ago, I don't want to see this name in my result).

I tried to solve this issue using aggregation, by creating a term aggregation over name, and then aggregating over max timestamp and then filtering records with max timestamp after one hour ago, as follows:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "names_aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_timestamp": {
          "max": {
            "field": "timestamp"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sub-agg": {
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "timestamp": {
                    "lt": "now-1h"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this query produces the following error:

```
{
  "type": "aggregation_initialization_exception",
  "reason": "Aggregator [max_timestamp] of type [max] cannot accept sub-aggregations"
}
```

I can basically get a similar functionality by using the timestamp filter before the max aggregation as follows:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "names_aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "maximals": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "timestamp": {
                "lt": "now-1h"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_timestamp": {
              "max": {
                "field": "timestamp"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indeed, I get a set of results with name and max_timestamp for each name that passed the maximals filter, and a null max_timestamp for each name that didn't pass the maximals filter. This is a solution I can work with, however, this query does not return for a large amount of records, because of the maximals filter that runs for each name.

Thanks in advance for your help.